Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist
I am trying to send a message from background script to content script in my chrome extension. But it looks like the message gets send before the content script is loaded?
This is the error I get when I am using my extension normally:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
This is my background script :
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, tab => {
        if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/card-application/apply/prospect/terms")) {
            console.log(tab.url);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, {
                type: "NEW",
                cardURL: tab.url
            });
        }
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/card-application/apply/prospect/terms")) {
        console.log(tab.url);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: "NEW",
            cardURL: tab.url
        });
    }
});

This is my contentScript.js code:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListenerdd((obj,sender,response) =>{
        const {type,value,pageURL}=obj;
        if(type==="NEW"){
            
            scrapeAmexData(pageURL)
            
        }
        console.log(currentPage)
    })
async function scrapeAmexData(url) {
console.log(url)
}

This is manifest.json file:
{
    "name": "Card tnc Details",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "scrap all credit card benefits & terms on Chase, American Express, Capital One and Citi",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.americanexpress.com/*"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.americanexpress.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [
          
        ],
        "matches": ["https://*.americanexpress.com/*"]
      }
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "assets/icon.png",
        "24": "assets/icon.png",
        "32": "assets/icon.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Card Tnc",
      "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}

